# Using a selector on a mapped div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, gsap

I am trying to use gsap to animate my `.gallery-item`'s with the following code:

```
const MoveItMoveIt = () => { 
   gsap.from('.gallery-item', { delay: .4,  duration: 3, y: 110, ease: "elastic(1, 0.5)", stagger: '0.4'}) 
}
```

And I have the gallery being mapped as so:

```
 {pets.map((pets) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-sm-4 gallery-item  text-center">
                <div className="" key={pets.user}>
                  <div className="">
                    snip
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
```

the problem is I am getting the error `gsap target not found`
I know this is because the function is firing in the milisecond before the `.gallery-item` exists and thus the function cannot find it.

I have tried an if statement to see if the `.gallery-item` exists, and then run the function. But the if statement just tells me that it doesn't exist. I have also tried to use the `setTimeout()` method to no avail.

How can I solve this timing issue? I am calling my function like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getPetInfo();
   
   
    
    MoveItMoveIt()
  }, []);
```

Comment: May be you can use MoveItMoveIt inside of useEffect with ref possibly.

Comment: I forgot to add, I am calling it within useEffect. I'll update the code

Comment: Please add a code sanbox or some link as providing skeleton does not help

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-moore-e5z8j?file=/src/components/pet-list.js 
I'm not sure why codesandbox is flagging it as a phishing site, but you can at least see all of the code.

Comment: https://greensock.com/react/  Please see Animating a Group of Elements

Comment: I think the problem is with getPetInfo(), if it's an API request then use async/await

Comment: getpetinfo() is using async await, do you mean to use it on my gsap function?

Comment: No use it with useEffect, useEffect(async () => { await getpetinfo() moveitmoveit() })

Comment: and by the way the key prop should be in first div after return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help commenters. I was able to solve this by putting my gsap function inside my api call.

```
 async function getPetInfo() {
    const response = await fetch(
      "my webhook url"
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    setPets(json.pets);
    MoveItMoveIt()
  }
  const MoveItMoveIt = () => { 
    const box = document.getElementsByClassName('.gallery-item')
      gsap.from('.gallery-item', { delay: .4,  duration: 3, y: 110, ease: "elastic(1, 0.5)", stagger: '0.4'})
  }
```

It now works as intended.

Comment: Please add correct syntax to help others.